# Was the weakness in Wraith technology ever revisited in any media?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

In the Season 2 episode "[Aurora](https://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s2/aurora/)", Sheppard's team discovers an Ancient warship by the same name. They learn from the Ancient crew whose consciousness is in some sort of virtual world that they are responsible for delivering information about a weakness of the Wraith.

> CAPTAIN: Nothing is lost. Not yet. I have vital information concerning a weakness in Wraith technology and when I deliver the communiqué in my possession, the tide will most certainly turn in our favor.
>
> SHEPPARD: That's right! The Atlantis mission log said you were on a recon mission. What-what-what kind of weakness are we talking about?
>
> CAPTAIN: That information is reserved for the Council.
>
> SHEPPARD: There is no Council any more!

Unfortunately, the information was destroyed by the end of the episode.

> CALDWELL: Both cruisers were destroyed in the explosion.
>
> DEX: It's too bad we weren't able to figure out the Wraith weakness.
>
> SHEPPARD: At least we found out they had one.

Was this weakness in Wraith technology ever revisited in any media (TV, comics, novels, etc)?

Comment: There were multiple issues that we know of; The critical error in Wraith hyperdrives to the [Attero Device](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Attero_device), the non-existence of their shields and susceptibility to drone strikes, the fact that their (hidden) cloning facilities are the only reason they can outbreed their losses, etc

Comment: @Valorum I guess the non-existence of the shields would be fairly obvious and not a secret weakness, even to pompous jerks like Ancients ;-)

Comment: @Rebel-Scum "Council, we've discovered a weakness in Wraith technology that will turn the tide of the war! Their ships don't have shields! If we just keep shooting them, they'll be destroyed!"

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - I was thinking more of the weaknesses presented by shieldless ships to drone strikes in certain areas of the hive ships.

Comment: @Valorum The Aurora had drone weapons, as well as other warships and Atlantis. I'm doubtful that firing their normal armament would be considered a top secret weakness.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Again, knowing precisely where to one-shot a hiveship with a drone would be a huge tactical advantage. You could arm a few puddle-jumpers and they could take out entire fleets.

Comment: Is there any proof that there was a weakness? Could the wraith not have manipulated the environment to give the ancients a reason to fix the hyper drive?

Comment: @Valorum hey knock that off, it’s thinking like that that could win the war!